# creating a different trigger for song request

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting an **error** on my
app as seen here:

```
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
12/22/23, 2:35:35 AM Greenwich Mean Time    onFormSubmit    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')    formSubmit  12/22/23, 2:35:35 AM Greenwich Mean Time
```

### My Script:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
Logger.log("Event Object: " + JSON.stringify(e));

var timestamp = e.values[0];
var name = e.values[1];
var songRequest = e.values[2];
var dedication = e.values[3];

var message = "New song request and dedication:\n\n";
message += "Timestamp: " + timestamp + "\n";
message += "Name: " + name + "\n";
message += "Song Request: " + songRequest + "\n";
message += "Dedication: " + dedication + "\n";

sendEmail("coolvibes1989@gmail.com", "New Song Request", message);
sendEmail("kay2043838@gmail.com", "New Song Request", message);
sendEmail("Shortdale4@gmail.com", "New Song Request", message);

// You can add more custom actions here, like updating a playlist or notifying someone else
}
```

I've been looking up the error online but can't for the sake of me find a fix or move forward on this.

Comment: What does JSON.stringify(e) look like?

Comment: If values is not present my guess is that you are using the wrong form submit trigger.  You want the one for the spreadsheet not the form

Answer (score 0):

This code with this trigger works just fine:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const [ts, n, sr, d] = e.values
  var message = "New song request and dedication:\n\n";
  message += "Timestamp: " + ts + "\n";
  message += "Name: " + n + "\n";
  message += "Song Request: " + sr + "\n";
  message += "Dedication: " + d + "\n";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv, "New Song Request", message);
}

function createMyTrigger() {
  const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyFormSubmit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyFormSubmit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

Sample Email:

[image]

Comment: ok thank you so much, could you please tell me if i can add width and height t this to make image bigger once form is submitted imageObject['myImage1'] = DriveApp.getFileById('1f6tbp4qeedm6pQdodoIrxR-e4dMNVsZp').getAs('image/png');